# Question about matrix relfections

Tags: matrices, reflection

The question is:

> Determine the matrix of the following reflection in $\Bbb R^2$:
>   $R$ is a relection in the line $x_1-5x_2 = 0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0.9231  &  0.3846 \\
0.3846  & -0.9231
\end{bmatrix}
$$
You can evaluate this easily by looking at a simple reflection in the first place. Say about the $1^{st}$ axis (corresponding to $x_{1}$). This can be represented by 
$$
\mathbf{I}_{ref} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{bmatrix}
$$
Now you can think of a general reflection about a line $x_{2} = tan(\theta)x_{1}$. Rotate the point in question by $-\theta$ about the origin (rotation matrix $\mathbf{R}_{-\theta}$). Now the reflection would be about the first axis ($\mathbf{I}_{ref}$). Now just rotate it back by $\theta$. The required reflection matrix is given by
$$
\mathbf{R}_{\theta} \mathbf{I}_{ref} \mathbf{R}_{-\theta}
$$

Comment: That is it. Thanks man!

Comment: @Konie I added in a small explanation.

Comment: @Konie Yu can also arrive at the same matrix, without needing to compute the angle with the [explicit form of the matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix#Reflection).